# Typescript filter by multiple values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and i want to filter it based on multiple values :

```
let books= [{ bookId : 1},{ bookId : 3},{ bookId : 4},{ bookId : 7},{ bookId : 10}];
let searchValues= [1,7];
let newArray = [];
```

i can use the spread operator like below :

```
searchValues.map(book=> {
  newArray.push(...books.filter(f => f.bookId== book.id));
});
```

but there a way to filter the array using a one liner like this or something similar ? :

```
newArray = books.filter(f => f.bookId in searchValues);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
newArray = books.filter(f => values.includes(f.bookId))
```

```js
let books = [
  { bookId: 1 },
  { bookId: 3 },
  { bookId: 4 },
  { bookId: 7 },
  { bookId: 10 },
]
let searchValues = [1, 7]
let newArray = []

newArray = books.filter((f) => searchValues.includes(f.bookId))

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: Short and sweet. Thank you :)